# output showing nil result in console when passing

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9.1

I am new iOS development and still learning basics, my query is when i passed the data to other view controller from my main tableView controller so it is passing smoothly but the output result is showing nil in the console as shown below 
[here as you can see output in console is nil.This is my second view controller named as movieDetailViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYRk7.png)

below is my main tableView controller from where i am calling my second view controller.

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? movieDetailViewController
    {
        destination.film = movies[(tables.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!] as? Movie
    }
  }
}
```

Here the structure Movie is a normal swift file containing attributes that i want to print shown as below:

```
import Foundation

struct Movie {

     var title: String
     var overview: String
     var poster_path: String

}
```

Now as i describe that output when passed to another view controller is showing nil. I have been stuck in this problem from 1 week and also searched a lot but no solution helped me in this .

Comment: `destination.film.title` is nil?

Comment: i already tried but output is nil

Comment: So `movies[(tables.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!].title` is nil then?

Comment: on my main tableViewController it is showing correct output but when passed to another view controller it prints nil.

Comment: Let me guess: You created the segue from the cell to the next viewcontroller? Remove it, and recreate it from initial viewcontroller to the next one, not from the cell.

Comment: yes i did the same thing but still nil :(

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't create the segue with a drag&drop where the initial point is the viewcontroller and not the cell?

Comment: Yes i checked it like around 1000 times its drag from main vc yellow trigger from to next vc yellow trigger as check 'show' on drop-down option

Comment: Can you share your project mdibrahimhassan@gmail.com

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan yes sir i did it. check your mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code in the movieTable View Controller class

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? movieDetailViewController
    {
        if let selectedIndex = tables.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row,
            let selectedTitle = movies[selectedIndex]["title"],
            let selectedOverView = movies[selectedIndex]["overview"],
            let selectedPosterPath : String = movies[selectedIndex]["poster_path"] as! String
            {
                destination.film = Movie.init(title: selectedTitle as! String, overView: selectedOverView as! String, posterPath:selectedPosterPath) as! Movie
            }
    }
}
```

Add an initialiser to your struct

```
init(title t: String, overView: String, posterPath pp: String) {
    title = t
    overview = overView
    poster_path = pp
}
```

Replace your `viewDidLoad` code in `movieDetailsViewController` to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let title = film?.title,
           let movieoverview = film?.overview,
            let urlString = film?.poster_path
        {
            movieTitle.text = title
            print(movieTitle.text)

            movieOverview.text = movieoverview

            print(movieOverview.text)

            let urlString = URL(string: ("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/") + urlString)
            moviePoster.downloadedFrom(url: urlString!)

        }


    }
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails", let destination = segue.destination as? movieDetailViewController {
        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, let indexPath = tables.indexPath(for: cell) {
            destination.film = movies[indexPath.row] as? Movie
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still output is nil

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


 let mv = movies[indexPath.row]

 performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: mv)


}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if let destination = segue.destination as? movieDetailViewController
{
    destination.film = sender as? Movie
}
}
```

Comment: output is same as nil :(

Comment: Can u post the initialization of ur array

Comment: var movies : [Movie]()
and Movie is the structure as i put in my query above.
And on movieDetailViewController i declare it as: 
var film:Movie?

Comment: It should be 
 
var movies  = [Movie]()    and append every object to it

Comment: oh sorry for my typo, yes it is var movies = [Movies]()

Comment: try to print movies array before performing the segue it would be nil , or there is a problem in the object initialization

Comment: i print the movies array and it gives me correct result

Comment: change declaration of film property in movieDetailViewController to var film = Movie()